# Layout not loading in the correct order aw_blog module

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, third-party-module

I'm currently facing a problem where the sidebar for the blog module of [aheadworks](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/blog.html) does not load inside the content.

Here's a screenschot[image: screenshot of page]

My layout.xml is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <block type="blog/blog" name="add.blog.footer">
                <action method="addBlogLink" ifconfig="blog/menu/footer"><param>footer</param></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="blog/menu_sidebar" name="right.blog.menu" before="-">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="blog/menu/right" ifvalue="1">
                    <template>aw_blog/menu.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="blog/tags" name="blog_tags" />
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="blog/menu_sidebar" name="left.blog.menu"  before="-">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="blog/menu/left">
                    <template>aw_blog/menu.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="blog/tags" name="blog_tags" />
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="blog/blog" name="add.blog.link">
                <action method="addBlogLink" ifconfig="blog/menu/top"><param>top</param></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>aw_blog/css/style.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <blog_index_index>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        <remove name="catalog.vertnav"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="blog/blog" name="blog" template="aw_blog/blog.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </blog_index_index>

    <blog_index_list>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        <remove name="catalog.vertnav"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="aw_blog_og" as="aw_blog_og" template="aw_blog/opengraph.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="blog/blog" name="blog" template="aw_blog/blog.phtml">
                <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </blog_index_list>

    <blog_post_view>
        <remove name="catalog.vertnav"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="aw_blog_og" as="aw_blog_og" template="aw_blog/opengraph.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml">
                <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </blog_post_view>

    <blog_cat_view>
        <remove name="catalog.vertnav"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="aw_blog_og" as="aw_blog_og" template="aw_blog/opengraph.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="blog/cat" name="cat" template="aw_blog/cat.phtml">
                <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="aw_blog_list_toolbar" template="aw_blog/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="blog/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </blog_cat_view>

    <blog_rss_index>
        <block type="blog/rss" output="toHtml" name="rss.blog.new"/>
    </blog_rss_index>
</layout>
```

This error only happens on the blog_post_view page.

Thanks in advance!

as reqeusted here is my 2 columns-left.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>" id="top" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>" id="top" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>" id="top" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>" id="top" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>" id="top" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MGV8FZ"
                  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MGV8FZ');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <?php
            $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
//            echo $action->getFullActionName('_');
            $array = array('customer_account_index', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_address_index', 'customer_address_form'
            , 'sales_order_history', 'sales_order_view', 'sales_order_invoice', 'sales_order_shipment', 'wishlist_index_index', 'wishlist_index_share', 'newsletter_manage_index'
            , 'rewardpoints_index_referral', 'rewardpoints_index_points', 'qquoteadv_view_history', 'qquoteadv_view_view', 'rma_rma_index', 'rma_rma_order', 'rma_rma_new_step1', 'rma_rma_new_step2', 'rma_rma_new_success', 'rma_rma_view', 'feedbackcompany_index_index', 'creditlimit_account_index', 'blog_index_list', 'blog_post_view', 'blog_cat_view');
            if (in_array($action->getFullActionName('_'), $array)) :?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                    <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
                    <div class="col s12 m3 sidebar">
                        <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
                            <?php echo $_leftContent;?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m9">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php else:  ?>
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
                <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
                <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share you 2 columns-left phtml file and also the url of your website?

Comment: I've added the 2 columns-left to the question, sharing the website won't be much of help because i'm not developing the blog on production @SukumarGorai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my own fault, the 2 columns-left.phtml on the server was different from the one i had in my git branch.

Thanks @sukumarGorai for pointing out the importance of 2 columns-left.phtml